# Where should I remove a notification observer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, notifications, nsnotifications

I set up a notification observer in my view controller's `init` method like so:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
                    addObserver:self
                    selector:@selector(saveState)
                    name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                    object:nil];
```

Where is the best place to call `removeObserver:name:object:` for this notification. I'm currently calling it in my `dealloc` method, but wanted to know if that might cause problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you got it right. `dealloc` is the correct location to remove notification observers (unless you have some specific reason to need to remove the observer earlier).

Comment: Thanks for this, nice to get confirmation.

Comment: Could you please post a reference to the official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can always remove the observer in `viewWillDisappear:`, or when you are done using it and have no other need for it, you can place it in a function.

Comment: Unless the view is going to appear again. I think your approach would work if I started the notification observer in `viewWillAppear:`.

Answer (score 1):

If the **-saveState** only need to execute once when active, then you can removeObserver inside the **-saveState**.

Comment: Presumably, he would want to save again if the app becomes active and then resigns active again.

Comment: You are right. I assuem he will register as an observer again when the app become active.

Comment: I just used `saveState` as an example, but it would probably need to be called over and over again (for example when the app will enter the background) so I like using `dealloc` better.